# Special character for input suggestions in autocomplete

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox in which i need to show the suggestions from which a user can choose and select one of them. however, suggestions only be shown when user enter @ character.
I don't want to hide @ and also want to show all suggestions without using @ in the name of that array. It is much similar like Facebook comment section where we use @ for our address book and when we select one then special character automatically removed.

Below is my Js file.

```
$(document).on('paste keyup', 'input[class="task"]', function () {
    var a = $(this).val();
    if (a === '@') {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: arr,
            minLength: 0,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).val((ui.item ? ui.item.id : ""));
            }
        }).on('focus keyup', function () {
            $(this).keydown();
            var isValid = false;
            for (i in arr) {
                if (arr[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
                    isValid = true;
                }
            }
            if (!isValid) {
                this.value = previousValue
            } else {
                previousValue = this.value;
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Please enter @ for task list");
    }
});
```

Note: arr is an array.

Comment: Try to use folding where you can define your own behavior for autocomplete search. You don't need to check for "@" separately on each key press.. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#folding

Comment: Can you please give me an example? I am not that good in jquery. I am checking @ only for a single textbox where user has to use value only from suggestions. these suggestions should be populated when first letter is @